# Missing / untracked files when trying to add Firebase to my project

Tags: ios, xcode, git, firebase

Files in my Xcode project (files from Firebase) got sent to trash. I do use source control, but I have no idea how to get the files to link back, I tried to add them back to the project manually and still nothing seems to help.

I have looked everywhere online, but git is really hard to understand. I do have access to a clean build of the project; do I need to git clone again and restart?

How can I just add these back?

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out:

1 -  I was using source control, that is why I could recover. Please always use source control. 
2 - Open terminal
3 - cd into your project
3.a git status
4 - git clean -f -d 
5 - git status  - to check what is going on in the branch
-> you will get a `working tree clean` message on terminal
6 - checkout - develop
7 - git pull 
Now I had weird errors and the fix was this:
I ran this 5 times (sometimes it takes many tries to take hold

1 - *clear derived data* (Xcode - project settings - > derived data and just send to trash the folders inside the derived data folder. 
2 - product -> *clean build folder*

- had to restart my computer

reopen project repeat steps 1 and 2 for cleaning the project.

- restart computer again

-> Happy running program